# Question about function on set of sets in Smullyan and Fitting - explanation sought

Tags: set-theory

Context: self-study and documentation on ProofWiki (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Smullyan and Fitting's *Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis* Chapter $4$: Superinduction, Well-Ordering and Choice: $\S 2$: Superinduction and Double Superinduction.

> Lemma $2.7$: For any set $S$: (1) If every element of $S$ is closed under a function $g$, so $\cap S$.

We are clearly talking about a set of sets. S&F have climbed down at the moment from talking about classes to explicitly considering sets for a moment, as they have something important they are building up to concerning superinduction.

But for the moment we consider $g$, and from where I'm sitting it is not clear what set $g$ is a function on. What is its domain, and what is its range? What *is* clear is that it operates on the elements of the elements of $S$, which themselves may of course be sets. It also seems to have in its domain the elements of $S$, so that is, its domain is not only the sets in $S$ but also the elements of the sets of $S$.

I'm having difficulty getting my head round this. Is anyone able to explain, who may have read their way round this subject (and in particular have themselves studied this specific point, whether in S&F or elsewhere): exactly what *is* the domain of $g$?

Comment: Why has this been voted to be closed for not providing context? I provided context!

Comment: The domain of $g$ must contain all the members of members of $S$ (as you said), but I don't see why it needs to also contain the members of $S$. In other words, the statement makes sense as long as the domain of $g$ is a superset of $\bigcup S$.  (With a clever definition of "closed under", it could make sense even more generally.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass If you were able to expand on this comment to explain what you mean in detail, then it could well be accepted as an answer. Hurry now before it gets closed. I *think* I know what you mean but unless the answer is in the shape of an actual answer, the existence of this question on MSE is pointless.

Comment: I don't understand what context needs to be added. I am self-studying with a view to improving and rounding out ProofWiki, which I have added a link for. What further context is needed? Seriously, I genuinely need to know. And what further details are needed? Apart from the suspicion that I'm being deliberately de-welcomed from MSE, for obvious reasons, why is this being flagged for closure?

Comment: I'm also not quite sure why this is flagged for closure.

Answer (score 2):

"Every element of $S$ is closed under the function $g$" means (1).$\forall s\in S\, (s\subseteq dom(g)\,)\;$ ( in other words $\bigcup S\subseteq dom (g)\;),$ and (2). $\forall s\in S\,(\{g(x):x\in s\}\subseteq s).$ Whether $\bigcup S\subsetneq dom (g)$ or $\bigcup S= dom (g)$ is irrelevant; the lemma is about $any$ $g$ that satisfies (1)and (2). For example if $S$ is a collection of sub-fields of $\Bbb R$ and $g(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.